# Angular way to bind an input to another variable until it has been touched?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with an always visible "new row" row whose field values should always mirror the row above until the user explicitly touch (focus on) one of the fields.

I thought of a solution using ES5 getters and setters, but I am wondering if there's any Angular way to do this?

I thought of using `Scope.$watch`, but I'll need to write a custom directive to use it, which will be a lot more code than the hack above.

Comment: "until the user explicitly touch (focus on) one of the fields" which fields ?

Comment: @Zakaria Each cell in the table will be an `<input>` which I called a field.